# Array initialization

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have two types of array initialisation that will be used in string constructor

```
int main() {
    //char foo [] = { 'a', 'd' }; 
    char foo[] = "ad";

    std::string s = foo;

    cout<<s;

    int i;
    cin >> i;
}
```

Why in `char foo [] = { 'a', 'd' };`  case i have output:

```
ad╠╠╠╠╠╠R8$1↑■╬
```

And when array is initialized like `char foo [] = "ad";` I have normal output -`ad`- that was expected in first case.

What is difference in these two array initialization and why I have garbage in output in first one?

Comment: `char foo [] = { 'a', 'd' };` does not have a terminating null character, but `char foo [] = "ad";` *does*.

Comment: omg people stop writing answers in comments ffs

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Those aren't really answers. They are kind of half-answers (a bit like the posted answers)

Comment: @juanchopanza: They totally don't belong in the comments section. The whole point of SO's existence is to do vote-ranked Q&A _properly_, not a willy-nilly assortment of half-answers, chatty tips and hints in a chronological list like a message board. I don't understand why everybody seems so intent on sabotaging this highly successful model all of a sudden. Unfortunately I also seem to be the only person who cares. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the string to be null terminated

```
char foo [] = { 'a', 'd', '\0' };
```

String literals are already null terminated.

> **§ 2.14.5 String Literals**
>
> 8 Ordinary string literals and UTF-8 string literals are also referred to as narrow string literals. **A narrow string literal has type “array of n `const char`”**, where n is the size of the string as defined below, and has static storage duration
>
> 14 After any necessary concatenation, in translation phase 7, **`'\0'` is appended to every string literal so that programs that scan a string can find its end**.

Comment: But `foo` isn't a `const char*`.

Comment: @CoryKramer: No, the literal is not a `const char*`.

Comment: No, a `char[]` isn't a thing in this context. There's more stuff going on, that you aren't really explaining.

Comment: @CoryKramer a string literal has the type of `array of n const char` (C++14 2.13.5(8))

Comment: I have updated the description of string literals with snippets from the C++ standard, hopefully that more thoroughly explains the behavior.

Comment: It goes 1/2 way. Why does this matter when constructing a string?

Answer (score 1):

In the case of `char foo [] = { 'a', 'd' };` you're declaring an array of characters which has two elements, i.e. not a null terminated string.  So when you try to print it as a string, the `<<` operator keeps reading whatever characters happen to follow until if finds a null byte.  This is undefined behavior.

In the case of `char foo [] = "ad";` you're initializing a character array with a string constant.  This constant has 3 characters, namely "a", "d", and a null byte, so the array is 3 characters long.  So when you print this, it prints properly.

Comment: Almost, but a bit misleading. I don't think your second paragraph is quite right.

Answer (score 1):

```
char foo[] = "ad";
```

Actually creates a `char` array of

```
char foo[] = { 'a', 'd', '\0' };
```

The `'\0'` is important as it is used to signal the end of a char array.  When you create the string `s` the contents of `foo` are read until the `'\0'` is reached.  When you output `s` you get `ad` .  When you do

```
char foo [] = { 'a', 'd' };
```

there is no `'\0'` so when you create the string `s` the constructor will keep going until it reaches a `'\0'`.  This is undefined behavior as we are using memory we have not allocated.

Comment: It is `s`, not `foo` that is being outputed.

Comment: @juanchopanza thanks for pointing that out.  fixed it to talk about the string creation.

Comment: I think the part that is missing is that there is no string constructor that can infer the length of an array, but there is one that takes `const char*`, so overload resolution picks that one after array decay.

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
std::string = foo; // copy ctor --  for std::string will be called
```

Which expects a null terminated ( C style) string. But in case of following you don't have a null character to terminate the C style string.

```
char foo [] = { 'a', 'd' }; // Incorrect
char foo[] =  { 'a', 'd' ,'\0'}; //Correct
```

It is fine in case of following as compiler will generate a null terminate C string for you.

```
char foo[] = "ad";
```

Also one thing to note that "ad" is a string literal, and { 'a', 'd' ,'\0'} is an array initializer. Following is notable here

```
char[] foo = "ad";
foo[1] = 'M'; // Undefined behavior 

char[] foo = { 'a', 'd' ,'\0'};
foo[1] = 'M'; // Is OK
```

Comment: _"as compiler will generate a null terminate C string for you"_ Right, but explain _why_. Explain what difference in the code leads to this happening.